# Table design to store Refund Transaction information

Tags: sql-server, database-design, table, data-warehouse

I have a transaction table that contains purchases and refunds. I'd like to create a linkage between purchase and refunds in the same table (I decided not to use a separate table). I'm not sure which direction the linkage should go. (One purchase can only have *one* refund - this is guaranteed)

- **Option 1** - Refund is linked to the purchase

| TrxID | amt | refundedTrxID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |  |
| 2 | -10 | 1 |

- **Option 2** - Purchase is linked to the Refund. (easy to see if a trx has a refund and which one it is)

| TrxID | amt | refundTrxID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2 |
| 2 | -10 |  |

Is there a standard way of modeling this? Or does it not matter since it's basically the same join?

SQL Server, but applicable to RDBMs

Comment: any chance there will be a partial refund? if yes then 1st option works better in my opinion otherwise the second one need to a comma-separated value until you normalise it

Comment: Will you have multiple refunds for the same purchase? Or multiple purchases refunded together? If the former then option 1, if the latter then option 2, if both then a third option is a many:many junction table containing the foreign keys of both as a composite primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go work option 1. You will always have a purchase, but not always a matching refund.

This way you could foreign key refund to an existing purchase on purchase_id; to ensure valid purchase exists for the refund.

Whereas with option 2, you could not foreign key purchase to to refund, as it would not exist yet. If you tried to go this route, you’d have to insert a row into refund when that happens, and then also turn around and update purchase with that info.

As for how easy to see what has a refund or not, you can always create views for that.